# What is the benefit of having the separate numbered databases in redis?

Tags: redis

I've been wondering why redis offers 16 'numbered' databases per instance. Could someone please explain the benefits of this, and the reason one might want to use multiple numbered databases on one server?

- Is it just another way of namespacing keys?
- Are there any performance benefits from separating out different key sets over different database numbers?

Answer (score 2):

Once convenient thing of databases is that you can flush them separately with FLUSHDB (while you cant flush all keys matching a pattern like 1*)

SORT and KEYS are also going to be faster if the keys you are interested are split in multiple dbs.